# django settings.py DATETIME_FORMAT: %M does not correspond to Minutes

Tags: python, django, datetime, format

according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats the following pattern should work if I put it into settings.py and deactivate USE_L1ON

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
```

When i use it, the '%' symbols are printed too, so i cahnged it to

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:M'
```

This, however, yields: 2013-04-10 09:Apr

So 'M' is translated to 'abbreviated month' instead of minutes. How can I fix this? The Django doc wasn't helpful

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for *input* of dates, while I suspect you are talking about formatting dates for *output* instead. You wanted https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were looking for [date *output* formatting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) and `i`:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i'
```

From the linked documentation:

> `i` - Minutes. - `'00'` to `'59'`